# Cross-Compilling Webkit2gtk from linux to windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-compiling, webkitgtk

Hello Good morning / afternoon / night,
I have started the development of an Application which needs an WebView, I discovered webkitgtk a while ago and I believe it's the best way to go since It already has a long support for linux and MacOS, but while compiling the app with mingw for windows I found a problem. I haven't found the dlls for the webkitgtk lib for windows, I already have the .so for linux and the Similar for mac but the windows dlls seem to don't exist. Then I thought to myself "I have a Cross-Compiler, Its just compile the source code of Webkitgtk". That's the question. I don't know how

Comment: Have you seen https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-aarch64/mingw64-webkitgtk-2.2.7-2.el7.noarch.rpm.html ?
I am working on Ubuntu, but if this works, I will switch to CentOS. Its more than a week I am pulling my hairs out because of mingw-w64-webkitgtk nightmare. No progress yet.

Comment: I am testing it

Comment: Unfortunally is 32 bit, Well I tried. My exit is use Servo or Netsurf when they finish dev and became a hole product

Comment: I switched to wine, a whole new hell! I was able to setup cmake and GCC. I am trying to solve make problem now, next step is adding webkitgtk dev files to system.

Comment: The problem I got is that my app is 64 bit and the package is 32 wich makes everything incompatible

Comment: Handling webview part could be specialized to use CHtmlView from MFC in windows. Not a good solution considering how much extra work should be done.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I am studying Uno right now, I provides a Webview, But it is not appearing on my gtk app